# How can I fix Flexslider height using Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, flexslider

I have a Flexslider post different size images. the problem is: I'm unable to fix or adjust this flex slider on one size.

jQuery Code:

```
if (jQuery(".kp-blogpost-slider").length > 0) {

        jQuery('.kp-blogpost-slider').each(function() {
            var $this = jQuery(this),
                    dataAnimation = $this.data('animation'),
                    dataDirection = $this.data('direction'),
                    dataSlideshowSpeed = $this.data('slideshow-speed'),
                    dataAnimationSpeed = $this.data('animation-speed'),
                    autoplay = $this.data('autoplay');

            $this.flexslider({
                animation: dataAnimation,
                direction: dataDirection,
                slideshowSpeed: dataSlideshowSpeed,
                animationSpeed: dataAnimationSpeed,
                smoothHeigh: true,
                controlNav: false,
                slideshow: autoplay,
                start: function(slider) {
                    jQuery(slider).removeClass('loading');
                }
            }); 
        });

    }
```

Comment: I think you need to make your slider responsive in CSS. did you use percentage on your images ? based on the height of the slider ?

Comment: i didn't use percentage on images. the height of the slider is not mentioned in css code

Answer (score 0):

These are all the possible options for flexslider with their default values as per [WooThemes Documentation](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/):

```
namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
animation: "fade",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
easing: "swing",               //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!
direction: "horizontal",        //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
animationLoop: true,             //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
smoothHeight: false,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode  
startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order

// Usability features
pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
pauseOnHover: false,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
useCSS: true,                   //{NEW} Boolean: Slider will use CSS3 transitions if available
touch: true,                    //{NEW} Boolean: Allow touch swipe navigation of the slider on touch-enabled devices
video: false,                   //{NEW} Boolean: If using video in the slider, will prevent CSS3 3D Transforms to avoid graphical glitches

// Primary Controls
controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item

// Secondary Navigation
keyboard: true,                 //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
multipleKeyboard: false,        //{NEW} Boolean: Allow keyboard navigation to affect multiple sliders. Default behavior cuts out keyboard navigation with more than one slider present.
mousewheel: false,              //{UPDATED} Boolean: Requires jquery.mousewheel.js (https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) - Allows slider navigating via mousewheel
pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
pauseText: 'Pause',             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
playText: 'Play',               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item

// Special properties
controlsContainer: "",          //{UPDATED} Selector: USE CLASS SELECTOR. Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the FlexSlider element. Example use would be ".flexslider-container". Property is ignored if given element is not found.
manualControls: "",             //Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Examples would be ".flex-control-nav li" or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
sync: "",                       //{NEW} Selector: Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider. Use with care.
asNavFor: "",                   //{NEW} Selector: Internal property exposed for turning the slider into a thumbnail navigation for another slider

// Carousel Options
itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
move: 0,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.

// Callback API
start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
end: function(){},              //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
added: function(){},            //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is added
removed: function(){}           //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is removed
```